# “file://” links working on one WordPress site but not the other. Both running on same server

Tags: networking, wordpress, intranet

I have 2 different WordPress sites on the same server. Both of them contain links to files on our internal network, which are linked using the `file://` protocol.

Here is the problem: On one of the sites the `file://` links work fine in Internet Explorer; I click the link and the folder location opens in a new window. However, on the other site when I click the `file://` links, absolutely nothing happens. What can I do to make this work on both sites?

The site with the working file links is using WordPress version 3.2.1

The site with the non-working file links is using version 3.5.1

Here is an example `file://` link that I am having this issue with:

```
file://servername/sharefolder$/sub1/sub2/sub3
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a link that works on one site, but not on the other? (By pasting both links here for comparison, with any private paths replaced)

Comment: Sure, apologize for not including that. its:  file://servername/sharefolder$/sub1/sub2/sub3

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the full path—or some pseudo-example of the path where you neuter specifics for privacy—hard to say what the issue is. But in general, the [`file://` URI (uniform resource identifier)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) scheme requires a hostname. And if there is no host connected to the `file://` URI, there should be three slashes (`///`) and not two (`//`).

So for example, if you wanted to access a file with the path `/hey/there/file` on your `localhost` setup, the URL could be this:

```
file://localhost/hey/there/file
```

Or could be this:

```
file:///hey/there/file
```

But there could also be an issue with the way WordPress 3.5.1 handles a `file://` URI versus how WordPress 3.2.1 would handle it. This [small chunklet of code on GitHubGist (from “rosshanney”](https://gist.github.com/rosshanney/3437658) seems to address the issue by creating a simple plugin method to allow `file` to be a part of the core `kses_allowed_protocols` in WordPress:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin name: Allow file protocol
*/

function rh_allow_file_protocol( $protocols ) {
    $protocols[] = 'file';
    return $protocols;
}

add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', 'rh_allow_file_protocol' )
```

Comment: Thanks for that Jake, but I've just tried it and it didn't fix the issue. I've added an example of the link that works on the other site in a reply to a comment above.